# How does the AWS Lambda charge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying the understand how the AWS Lambda charge. I know that the first 1 million requests and the first 400000GB-second compute time if free are free. After that, it will charge 0.20USD per million requests and 400,000 seconds if the function is 1GB RAM. What I am not clear here is how the computing time is charged.

Let's say one request is "0.0000002USD". One the client makes the request, it already charged 0.0000002USD no matter how long it was run. The computing time is charged once the function starts running based on how much memory it consumes and how long it was run for. Is that correct? Let's say the function was run for 2 hours, but it only consumed 1GB RAM (which is not realistic - just for the educational purpose), so it is gonna charge me 0.0000002USD + (cost of execution/ computing for 400,000 seconds). Am I right?

Can anyone confirm and explain?

Comment: This is spelled out in the documentation, along with a lot of examples. [Lambda Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple costs involved.

You pay a per-request cost, and a per-second cost. The amount of the per-second cost depends on how much RAM you assign to the function. The longer your Lambda functions run, the more they cost. The more RAM they require, the more they cost.

There's no need to do a bunch of guesswork - AWS provides [a calculator](https://s3.amazonaws.com/lambda-tools/pricing-calculator.html), and it'll even do the math on the free tier. Put in some numbers and see how the charge changes.

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need some information like `includeFreeTier`, `numExecutions`, `numExecutions` and `allocatedMemory`

```
executionsToCount = includeFreeTier ? (numExecutions - 1000000) : numExecutions;

computeGBS = numExecutions * (executionTime/1000) * (allocatedMemory/1024);
totalCompute = includeFreeTier ? (computeGBS - 400000) : computeGBS;

requestCosts = max(executionsToCount, 0) / 1000000 * .20;
executionCosts = max(totalCompute, 0) * 0.00001667;

finalCost = requestCosts + executionCosts
```